# Remove items from two vectors depending on the values inside one vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have two integer vectors of equal length. Let's say I want to remove all items in the first vector which are NAN. Obviously, I use the remove_if algorithm. Let's say this removes elements that were at indexes 1,2,5. I then want to remove items from the second vector at these indexes.

What's the most canonical C++ way of doing this?

Comment: If they are related values, the most canonical way would be to put both pieces of data in the same object and have one vector containing those objects...

Comment: like @cdhowie said, if you know they have the same length and the values are linked you should probably have a `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` in the first place

Answer (score 11):

This can be done using Boost by creating a [`zip_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) and then iterating over the `tuple` of iterators from both containers in parallel.

First pass a pair of `zip_iterators` to `std::remove_if`, and have the predicate inspect the elements of the first `vector` for NaN

```
auto result = std::remove_if(boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(v1.begin(), v2.begin())),
                             boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(v1.end(),   v2.end())),
                             [](boost::tuple<double, int> const& elem) {
                                 return std::isnan(boost::get<0>(elem));
                             });
```

Then use `vector::erase` to remove the unneeded elements.

```
v1.erase(boost::get<0>(result.get_iterator_tuple()), v1.end());
v2.erase(boost::get<1>(result.get_iterator_tuple()), v2.end());
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4085cf2054ac860)

---

The boilerplate required to create the zipped iterator ranges can be further reduced by using [`boost::combine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/combine.html) and Boost.Range's version of [`remove_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/remove_if.html).

```
auto result = boost::remove_if(boost::combine(v1, v2),
                               [](boost::tuple<double, int> const& elem) {
                                    return std::isnan(boost::get<0>(elem));
                               });
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be25435848f6cf58)

Comment: This is awesome.  Thanks!  I chose to use boost::combine to produce a range which I could call begin() and end() on in remove_if, I presume there's no real difference?

Comment: @experquisite That's an excellent idea, cleans the code up quite a bit. I added that to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `vector<pair<int, int>>` to *tie* the two vector together.  Then, perform your remove based on the first element to and get rid of both at the same time.