# Remove elements from two std::vectors based on the first vector's elements

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I have to vectors with the same amount of elements. I would like to remove the elements of the first vector based on a condition but I would also like to remove from the second vector the elements that are on the same position.

For example, here are two vectors:

```
std::vector<std::string> first = {"one", "two", "one", "three"}
std::vector<double> second = {15.18, 14.2, 2.3, 153.3}
```

And what I want is to remove based on the condition if the element is "one". The final outcome is:

```
std::vector<std::string> first = {"two", "three"}
std::vector<double> second = {14.2, 153.3}
```

I can remove the elements from `first` by using:

```
bool pred(std::string name) {
  return name == "one";
}

void main() {

  std::vector<std::string> first = {"one", "two", "one", "three"}
  first.erase(first.begin(), first.end(), pred);

}
```

But I am not aware of a way to remove elements from the second vector as well.

Comment: You could use a `for` loop with indexing, where you will need to use one index for both vectors. This way you erase from both vectors on the same index

Comment: One way to do this is using zip iterators from Boost - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26659114/241631

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you change your data structure.
Use a structure to hold the two elements:

```
struct Entry
{
  std::string text;
  double      value;
};
```

Now this becomes one vector of two elements:
`std::vector<Entry> first_and_second;`

When you search the vector for a given text, you can remove one element containing both text and value.

Comment: Or just use a `std::multimap<std::string, double>`.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: Yes, your suggestion is an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = first.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
   if(first[i] == "one"){
       first.erase(first.begin() + i);
       second.erase(second.begin() + i);
   }
}
```