# Removing elements marked for removal with Ranges-V3

Tags: c++, c++17, range-v3, erase-remove-idiom

I've got two vectors:

```
struct MyData{
     double value; 
};
std::vector<int> remove_flags = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
std::vector<MyData> data =      {{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}};
```

The `remove_flags` vector contains an array of flags of the exact same size as `data`, each flag is either 0, or 1, where 1 means the data should be removed.

I would like to use `remove_flags` to remove elements from `data` in place, ie performing the erase remove idiom, but erasing based on values in `remove_flags`.  The end result should be `data` with elements erased, and hopefully `remove_flags` with those same elements erased.

Doing this manually is annoying, and I wanted to use Range-v3 for this.  I'm currently using C++17.

After looking through the documentation, I don't think I've found a solution, the closest thing I could come up with is:

```
auto result = ranges::views::zip(remove_flags, data) | ranges::actions::remove_if([](std::pair<const int&, const MyData&> pair){
    return pair.first != 0;
});

remove_flags.erase(result.first, remove_flags.end());
data.erase(result.second, data.end());
```

But actions cannot operate on the view zip, so this does not compile. If I switch `ranges::actions::remove_if` to `ranges::views::remove_if` a strange views object is returned, presumably one that has not actually performed the `std::remove` equivalent operation on the two vectors.

I *could* use `contaner_to` but that would involve a copy, and I don't want to pay that kind of unnecessary penalty for convenience. [I've seen what I want accomplished in boost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26659114/2036035) where actual zip pair iterators can be used to return two separate removal results.

Is this kind of pattern possible in Range-v3?

Comment: Is there a reason why you actually want a `std::vector` of the results? Isn't a view enough?

Comment: @Enlico Please clarify your question, no where in my post do I mention or demonstrate a "standard vector of result".  In fact, it's impossible for my example to show this, since I say `result.first` and `result.second`

Comment: The last two lines of your snippet show that you alter both `data` and `remove_flags`, so I think it's fair to presume you want to use _those_ afterward, i.e. those two _`std::vector`s_ contain the "output/result/effect" you want to achieve. That's where you "mention" in your post that you want the result of the code to be in a `std::vector`
 (_result_, not _`result`_, just as in my previous comment). However, let's put it in another way: your example is not a [repro]; can you either make it one or describe in words what the desired outcome/result/effect of the code is?

Comment: @Enlico the above example now represents an MVCE, and I've clarified what I want.  Note, the title was not separate from my post, and that the boost example (first part) gives effectively what I want exactly, just with out range syntax.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've deleted my answer for now, because it's clearly not a good answer at the moment. I don't have any idea at the moment. I'd be curious to know why you need to remove the elments in place, and having a view on them is not enough.

Comment: @Enlico In real code, `MyData` represents Dear ImGUI table row items. Because ImGUI is immediate mode, in order to remove elements from the UI, I must first mark elements some how (ie selection) *then* remove them afterwards, as displaying rows is literally a for loop that runs each time.   Again, it's UI is immediate mode, selection doesn't persist with out **me** creating an array that maintains the selection (effectively `remove_flags`).  Removing these elements removes the UI rows. These rows also represent markers, removing the `MyData` then also removes the markers (which is desired).

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying this. I have just one misunderstanding left: how is the loop done? If it was done via `for (auto x : result)` or `for (auto it = result.begin(); it != result.end(); ++it)`, then a view would be fine.

Comment: @Enlico So the loop effectively looks something like (in half psuedo code) `if(ImGui::BeginTable()){ ...; clipped.Begin(data.size()); for(int row_n = clipped.Start; row_n < clipped.End; ++i){ auto& my_data = data[row_n]; if(ImGui::Selectable("",remove_flags[row_n],...){...};if(ImGui::DisplayColumn(0)){ ImGui::InputText("input", &(my_data.name))}; if(ImGui::DisplayColumn(1)){...}}ImGui::EndTable();}`  The loop is not trivial, I need references to mydata inside the loop itself, I use the values of my_data inside the loop itself, need to modify it from within the generated UI.

Comment: @Enlico if this code looks weird, that's because this his how ImGUI is architected, see here: https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/c6c82b9f1de6ef3e298050656a1cf0a499d4e808/imgui_demo.cpp#L5074

Comment: Oww... to far from my way of coding.

Answer (score 6):

Eager operation on existing ranges is the domain of algorithms. The only slightly
tricky bit here is recovering iterators into the vectors since `zip` doesn't give you a direct way to get those. So instead recover them using the distance between the new end and the start of the range:

```cpp
auto z = ranges::views::zip(remove_flags, data);
auto e = ranges::remove_if(z, [](auto&& r){ return r.first; });
data.erase(data.begin() + (e - z.begin()), data.end());
remove_flags.erase(remove_flags.begin() + (e - z.begin()), remove_flags.end());
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rsTW3nfc6).